# Nginx качает файл index.php вместо того чтобы запустить егою

Tags: php, linux

Всем привет. В этом деле я новичок, нагуглил целую гору решений- ни одно не помогло.

//**php-fpm7.0**

// Также в файле /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini **cgi.fix_pathinfo=0**

**sites-available/ default.conf:**

```
 server {
    server_name project.example;
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ipv6only=on;

    # You need to add your SSL certs here
    ssl_certificate /path/to/mydomain.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/mydomain.com.key;
    ssl_dhparam /path/to/dhparam.pem;

    root /var/www/html/index.php;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
           deny all;
    }
}

#Default server
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    return 401;
}
```

**sites-enabled/ defalut.conf:**

```
    ##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: Пользовался слово в слово данным гайдом https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-20-04-ru - не помогло.

Comment: HTML открывает без проблем.

Comment: Приложите вывод`systemctl status php-fpm`, `ls /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock` и проверьте другие конфиги, возможно в каком-то из них переопределяются параметры.

Comment: благодарю, но пока читал коммент мне еще подсказали куда посмотреть.

Answer (score 0):

Может кому поможет.

1. Переместить рабочую папку с проектом из var/www в home/#username/#ваш_проект
2. Добавить конфиг сервера в нетронутый default.conf (sites-available) в самый конец файла, не забыл прописать корректный путь из п.1.
3. Файл etc/hosts - прописать название папки с проектом после ip например
   127.0.0.1 romashka

Мне помогли только эти 3 простых действия.
Возможно у кого то файл hosts нетронутый, но у меня он ссылался на папку var/www/#проект а там я уверен была проблема с правами доступа.